# Sentence Completion: "The narratives that vanquished people.. manage to ____ the victor's triumph.. "

Tags: sentence

Here is the sentence:

> The narratives that vanquished people have created of their defeat
>   have, according to Schivelbusch, fallen into several identifiable
>   types. In one of these, the vanquished manage to (i)_____ the victor's
>   triumph as the result of some spurious advantage, the victors being
>   truly inferior where it counts. Often the winners (ii)____ this
>   interpretation, worrying about the cultural or moral costs of their
>   triumph and so giving some credence to the losers' story.

**My Interpretation:** 
For the first blank, I was able to figure out the correct option. The vanquished people 'interpret' (seemingly undermining) that the victor won due to some advantage and not due to his true vigor or skills. (Am I right?)

I am essentially confounded by the second blank. I'm not even able to incisively distinguish between the actors involved in this excerpt. Who are the vanquished talking about? Vanquished themselves are the winners, aren't they? So are the winners writing about themselves? Are these 'narratives' tantamount to biographies? And then, in the last sentence, who are the (new) winners?

Anyway, for the second blank, following are the options given. A holistic approach towards the interpretation will be helpful, however.

> (ii) take issue with (i think this one fits); disregard; collude in

Comment: Thank you for your selection, Vaibhav. I would recommend that you should usually not making an official selection so quickly - let your question remain "active" so others in the community, many who are much more knowledgeable than I am, will be motivated to answer and provide good commentary.

Comment: Sure, will keep in mind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the winners **collude in** this interpretation, [*hoping to not make worse or exacerbate the*] cultural or moral costs of their triumph and [*as a result of this collusion*] so giving some credence to the losers' story.

The "vanquished" are those who have lost the war and who have created a narrative of their loss which is meant to downplay the superiority of the "victors" by interpreting their loss to be as a result of "some spurious advantage" allowing the vanquished to claim that inspite of their (the vanquished) loss, the victors were "truly inferior where it counts".

> **Vanquish** *verb* past tense: vanquished; past participle: **vanquished**
>
> **to defeat thoroughly**. "Mexican forces *vanquished* the French army in a battle in Puebla"
>
> *synonyms*: conquer, defeat, beat, trounce, rout, triumph over, be victorious over; see, Google.com [**vanquish**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=vanquished+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: But collusion means to conspire. How do the winners conspire to the interpretation? Also, who are the 'vanquished' ? Aren't they the winners themselves (that's what 'vanquished' literally means)?

Comment: The "victors" collude or go along with or don't strongly refute the interpretations of the "vanquished" explaining the reasons for their loss, in the hope that this "collusion" will allow the "victors" to avoid or minimize "the cultural or moral costs of their triumph".

Comment: "collude" here means: to play a (unacknowledged) role in, to be partly responsible.

Comment: The 'vanquished' are the winners or the losers? "vanquished people have created of their defeat have".. suggests that they are the losers who are trying to undermine or qualify the winner's victory. Is that right? 

Though the denotation of these words ('vanqueshed' & 'collude') do not fit in to context properly, it seems that I am now getting what the connotation actually is. 

So, if the vanquished ARE the losers and by your last comment, it seems plausible that the winners are just being too modest to collude (agree) in to the loser's interpretation to protect the cultural/moral interests!

Comment: Right, from that 'edit' it's clear. THanks for the help Eva.

Comment: In an attempt to avoid or minimize the "cultural or moral costs of their triumph" the victors do not strongly object to or refute (hence, "collusion") the interpretations of the vanquished explaining the reasons for their loss.